# Joining a date and time into a single cell in Excel / VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to report basically the same information from inspections to two different clients, both of whom have provided me with an Excel spreadsheet in their own preferred format, and password protected. I have put the two sheets into my own workbook, and have managed to get 'almost' all the data on both sheets to populate from my own data. Where I am stuck though is on the time logs.

Client 'A' has each time and date in a single column, in the format "12.29.12 14:30". Client 'B' has two columns, date as "12/29/12" in the first, and time as "1430" in the second.

I'm trying to avoid having to type all the same dates and times twice - it can be several dozen lines - both to save effort and to avoid errors. What I really need to do is either concatenate the date and time from client 'B's report and put it into client 'A's, or split the date and time up in 'A's so I can put it ito 'B's. I've tried several approaches, but just end up with error codes or meaningless numbers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Richard

Never mind... the very next thing I tried worked :-)

To anyone else reading this, the trick is not to concatentate the date and time values, but to add them together.

Richard

Comment: Please provide your answer as an answer. Related to my request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108969/best-way-to-deal-with-questions-answered-by-the-op-in-the-question-instead-of-in

Comment: I tried to post it as an answer, but the site said I cannot answer my own question with a new user reputation, so to edit my question.

Comment: Ah, pardon my ignorance. According to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is You should be able to answer it in about 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

As you later pointed out in your own question, in order to manipulate date/times in Excel, you should add instead of concatenating.

The reason for this is that Excel stores all date/times as a number representing the number of days since January 1, 1900*. [This number is stored as a 8-byte double.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687869%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Use Excel number formats to display the date/time format that you desire.

If you find in a worksheet that some cell's dates are in fact stored as text, use the [DATEVALUE function.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx)

*By default, Excel 2010 for Windows uses the number of days since 1900. There is an option to use the number of days since 1904 for compatibility with other versions.